# Creating macros for the excel sheet in VBscript or Javascript

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I have been using VBscript for writing macros in the excel. But can I write javascript as well for writing the macros?

If yes , then which is much better and why?

Answer (score 2):

Excel macros can't be written in either VBScript or JavaScript. The language used in Microsoft Office macros is VBA (Visual Basic for Applications), which is similar to VBScript, but [not identical](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970436.aspx).

What you can do with both VBScript and JavaScript is [COM automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) of Office applications (running from `.vbs` or `.js` files respectively):

```js
var xl = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
xl.Visible = true;

var wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\\path\\to\\your.xlsx");
var ws = wb.Sheets(1);

ws.Cells(1,1).Value = "something";

wb.Save();
wb.Close();
xl.Quit();
```

However, you'll still be using VBA objects and methods that way.